# Given the numerical value of Hue, Saturation and Value, how to tell the name of color using a color wheel

Tags: opencv, hsv, color-wheel

In the following color wheel, each color name has a single numerical value written beside it, and no range (like 60-75).

If there was a numerical range written, I would compare my Hue value with the ranges, and when the hue fell into a range (e.g. the range was 60-75 and hue was 69), I would give that color the name corresponding to that range.

Now, how do I name a color, given its Hue (and saturation and value, if those are used)? Suppose I have a color with a hue=69. What will I name it?

[image]

Comment: So you want an HSL color wheel? I mean you can google one real quick but basically Hue defines the color and Luminance defines how "bright" it is. Link to color wheel below http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm

Comment: probably there is no name for each color value but only for some representatives. 69 would just be somewhere between cool yellow and mid yellow. if you want to assign ranges to names hthen you would probably choose 52-67 as mid yellow and 68-83 as cool yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your color wheel actually looks like **HSL** (without saturation at all), not **HSV** - some more info can be found in [wiki description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

And about your question - I suppose that you can define your bins manually - as I see, there is fixed step between colors, and you can set limits to **7** in each direction (i. e. *58-67* for *mid yellow*, *68-82* for *cool yellow* etc.). Then you can determine **hue** bin and use name from your color wheel.